# Average of subarrays of length k in C++

Tags: c++, array, stl

I took a crack at solving the problem of finding the averages of all subarrays of length k. Here is what I came up with. I would greatly appreciate your feedback on  my code.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <numeric>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

vector<double> findSuseqAverages(size_t k, const vector<int>& nums) {

    vector<double> res (nums.size() - k + 1);
    auto left_it = nums.begin();
    auto right_it = next(left_it, k);
    double curr_sum = accumulate(left_it, right_it, 0);

    size_t res_index = 0;
    res.at(res_index) = curr_sum / k;

    while (right_it != nums.end()) { 
        curr_sum += *right_it - *left_it;
        res.at(++res_index) = curr_sum / k;        
        ++right_it;
        ++left_it;         
    }

    return res;
}  

int main() {
    vector<int> nums {-1, 0, 1};
    size_t k = 2;
    vector<double> averages = findSuseqAverages(k, nums);

    for (const auto& a: averages) cout << a << " ";
    cout << "\n\n";
}
```

Comment: Please be aware that editing the question after it has been answered may not be allowed if it invalidates the answer.

Comment: Refer to https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers and the "What should I NOT do" header, which expands upon pacmaninbw's comment.

Comment: Sorry about that. I am new here. Just removed the "using namespace std"

Comment: You should also check whether k is at most the length of the array. What is the desired behavior for invalid input?

Answer (score 3):

Generally the code is well written, there are only a few items that need commenting on.

### Avoid Using Namespace `std`

If you are coding professionally you probably should get out of the habit of using the `using namespace std;` statement. The code will more clearly define where `cout` and other identifiers are coming from (`std::cin`, `std::cout`). As you start using namespaces in your code it is better to identify where each function comes from because there may be function name collisions from different namespaces. The identifier `cout` you may override within your own classes. This [stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice) discusses this in more detail.

### Use Braces Around Single Statements in Program Flow

Primarily for maintenance reasons it is a good habit to create code blocks within if statements, else clauses and within loops. Many bugs have been created during maintenance when one or more statements was added to an if statement or a loop.

From this code:

```
    for (const auto& a: averages) cout << a << " ";
```

Would be better as

```
    for (const auto& a: averages) {
        std::cout << a << " ";
    }
```

Then if someone needs to add a statement to the for loop at some point it is quite simple.

### This Code Could Be Simplified

```
    vector<double> res (nums.size() - k + 1);
        ...

    size_t res_index = 0;
    res.at(res_index) = curr_sum / k;

    while (right_it != nums.end()) { 
        ...
        res.at(++res_index) = curr_sum / k;      
        ...  
    }
```

It's not clear why it was necessary to initialize the `res` vector to the proper size in the previous code. Since vectors are variable sized they don't need to be initialized with a size.

```
    std::vector<double> res;
        ...

    res.push_back(curr_sum / k);

    while (right_it != nums.end()) { 
        ...
        res.push_back(curr_sum / k);      
        ...  
    }
```

removes one variable and achieves the same result.

Comment: There is an efficiency gain by initializing `res` to the proper length.  It can avoid multiple reallocs and move copies, especially useful when the length of the input data becomes very large ... often seen in these types of problems seen on programming challenge sites.

Comment: @AJNeufeld then wouldn't an iterator be better than using an index?

Comment: [`std::vector::reserve(...)`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/reserve) & `push_back()` would be best.

Answer (score 1):

## Don't `using namespace std;`

Ever.

## Check that `k` is reasonable

If `k` is greater than the number of elements, we overflow `std::size_t` when computing the size of our results array.  We should detect this case, and return an empty vector.

Also, if `k` is zero, then the call is meaningless - return early or throw an exception in that case.